# Unix System static Date get change automatically

Tags: linux, unix, unix-timestamp

Thanks for taking time to look into my issue ,  we have VM Server (cent os) on which we are setting up static date , as per business requirement and we need to maintain same date so we have schedule cron to set date back to 23rd June 2017 at 12 midnight , but from few days during business working hrs around 3 PM date get change automatically to current date,  which ends up with Application outage during that.

Possible solution we tried : 
1. uninstalled ntp to avoid any date set.
2. vmware sync is disable.
3. date set cron job disable for time being.
4. rebooted server to fix this issue but found below result.

[root@xxxx-t01 ~]# hwclock -u
Fri 23 Jun 2017 04:42:05 PM PDT  -0.547072 seconds
[root@xxxx-t01 ~]# date -u
Wed Apr  4 23:42:44 UTC 2018
[root@xxx-t01 ~]#

System date and hardware date is different after reboot. we fix that with timezone setup.

we tried with other solution to capture events like var/logs/messages but we couldn't get any events to capture, which can be suspicious.

Looking for valuable inputs to check how exactly date get change, is there any way that we can capture any external source is trying to do some action on server so date is changing to current date.

Appreciate your help.

cheers,
Santosh

Comment: Why do you need to maintain the same date?

Comment: its business requirement as they need to keep in sync some data with some external source of data on fixed date so its static date.

Answer (score 0):

i hope i got you right. Imo the following solution should
work just fine!

Try the following:

```
# disable - ntp
timedatectl set-ntp 0

# disable chronyd (the "ntp-service")
systemctl stop chronyd
systemctl disable chronyd
# or 
systemctl mask chronyd 

# set your system time
date -s [your time]

# set your hardware time based on system time
hwclock -w
```

There are also some hwclock-debug options available you can make
use of.

As last line of "defense" (against clock-update) you
could block the ntp port, via firewall-cmd / iptables.

Comment: we already remove ntp ,to prevent this issue but still we are facing issue